# NodeJs in other drive opens up notepad instead

Tags: node.js

calling node in command line open up node console from c drive, but calling in e drive opens notepad instead

```
E:\work\working_dir
λ node

E:\work\working_dir
λ c:

C:\Users\eudem
λ node
> process.exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to have a "node.txt" in E:\work\working_dir? Windows by default hides file extensions, so it might not be obvious.

Comment: just starting to learn node, didn't know this would cause conflict, I had node.js file in that directory, renaming it to something else works fine